# Why it is impossible to access LogStream of a Managed Application App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-managed-app

We have a managed application published in Microsoft Partner Center, for preview audience.

We have both publisher and client tenants. After installing the app into the client's tenant I can't access the log steam of the installed app from either publisher / client tenants.
When I'm trying to open Log Stream i can see only "connecting....".

Previously, as i have described here, we were able to access logstream using Visual Studio. However, Visual Studio log stream has stopped working as well.

We cannot access log stream at all!

Why this is happening and how can i access log stream of a Managed Application App Service?

[image: Web Log Stream]
[image: VisualStudio Code Log Stream]

Comment: We can use Azure CLI command to check the logs.Use `az webapp log show --name YourAppName --resource-group RGName`  and check once.

Comment: Have you checked this [ARM Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/managed-applications/publish-service-catalog-app?tabs=azure-powershell#create-the-arm-template) to create a Managed Application.Iam able to see the logs with this.

Comment: We can also use `az webapp log tail --` as well to see the excat same logs of LogStream.

Comment: It is working from the cmd, doesnt work on portal and visual studio. It never worked on the portal, it worked in Visual studio before, however stopped working like a month ago. I tried log out/in, clear cache, reinstall app... nothing.
At least it works in cmd, so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have referred the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/managed-applications/overview) which is provided in the Managed Applications in Azure Portal.

[image]

- I have created a managed Application using the [ARM Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/managed-applications/publish-service-catalog-app?tabs=azure-powershell).
- Enable the App Service Logs and the required Level of Logging.

[image]

- Iam able to see the Logs from Log Stream.

[image]

> how can i access log stream of a Managed Application App Service?

We can use [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/log?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-log-tail) command to check the Logs.

```cs
az webapp log tail --name YourAppName --resource-group RGName
```

```cs
2023-09-26T12:05:16  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service. The default timeout is 2 hours. Change the timeout with the App Setting SCM_LOGSTREAM_TIMEOUT (in seconds). 
2023-09-26 12:05:05 ~**** GET /api/deployments/ $orderby=ReceivedTime%20desc&$top=20&api-version=2022-03-01&X-ARR-LOG-ID=1f24b085-e6a8-4b78-87ae-215dcb4e1648 443 - 13.66.140.0 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/117.0.0.0+Safari/537.36+Edg/117.0.2045.43 - https://edge.management.azure.com/subscriptions/****/resourceGroups/****/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/****/deployments?$orderby=ReceivedTime%20desc&$top=20&api-version=2022-03-01 ****.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 781 7791 33
2023-09-26 12:05:10 **** GET / X-ARR-LOG-ID=cec75a96-a5c8-47c4-ba94-b935331a0ecf 443 - 115.110.154.186 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/117.0.0.0+Safari/537.36+Edg/117.0.2045.43 - https://sandbox-97-2.reactblade-ms.portal.azure.net/ ****.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 2136 1544 1594
2023-09-26 12:05:11 **** GET / X-ARR-LOG-ID=6438e91b-cd03-4ec5-ba0e-b258b9ce7e1f 443 - 65.154.226.169 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/106.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 - http://****.azurewebsites.net ****.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 1851 1037 12
```

Comment: I did turn on logging in the App Service Logs tab, it still doesnt work on the web site.
It is working tho in cmd (so far). Thanks for the tip!
The thing is, logging never worked for me on the web portal, it worked before in VIstual studio, however stopped working like a month ago.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @DavidMakogon - Sure.The images are the log files.

Comment: I understand what the images represent. The problem is that it's a screenshot of text, and shouldn't be posted as a screenshot (see the page I linked to, which provides many reasons to avoid doing this)

Comment: Ok..Will update it accordingly.